# How to make solid color to transparent with CSS in the scenario below?

Tags: html, css, spinner

I use the spinner in this site "http://projects.lukehaas.me/css-loaders/" .  the 3rd one in first row.  it will show a solid color when I apply to my system in the center of the circle. I want to make it transparent. but it will white circle will turn wrong if I did that. What I want is to transparent the solid background in the middle of the torus and hide the color in it too.  Could anybody help me with this? thanks very much.

Comment: You can't do that with the loader you picked. It uses a solid color to mask the gradient that makes up the trail; you can clearly see this if you delete the `::after` pseudoelement. You'd have to come up with a completely different solution; perhaps try using an SVG or an image instead, or just use a different loader. Either way, you'll also need to at least try to solve it yourself, and post your efforts. We're here to help you solve problems you've tried to solve yourself. We aren't here to build loaders for you for free.

Comment: Thank you for your details reply. I have changed the implement of the loader based on this demo.  and it works fine. thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have half a donut, fading to transparent on one side

```css
body {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
.test {
    width: 240px;
    height: 240px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.test:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 160px;
    height: 160px;
    left: 0px;
    border: solid 40px red;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-left-color: transparent;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
   
}

.test:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 160px;
    height: 160px;
    left: 40px;
    top: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 118px 30px 120px 40px red;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

The base element is used just for clipping to a circle.

Then a pseudo element gives the solid half circle, using borders.

And another pseudo element uses a shadow to make the fading red. For this kind of setups, it is very convenient that the shadow is clipped by the element on wich it is set. So, if this element has the size of the inner circle, the shadow is clipped by both circles

Answer (score 0):

By default even the source site you mentioned has a solid color in the middle.

You can just keep the `background-color` of the circle in the middle same as the background's `background-color`. That is what they did in their site's page too(In the link you provided).

If you inspect element, you can see what selector to use for the inner circle. Here in the link you provided, it is`.load3 .loader:after`.
Changing background-color`.load3 .loader:after` to transparent would change the loader's shape because the loader is not actually a beam circling around, it is actually a quadrant.

What am telling here may not make sense unless you see it for yourself.
Try changing the `background` of `.load3 .loader:after` in the link you provided to `background:transparent` using `inspect element` and you will know what am talking about.

Comment: Yes I know what you talk about. I solve this by change the implement of the load(not use the quadrant).  Thanks you for your answer all the same.